# How to allow only a certain number of words?

Tags: java

Say I have a Scanner, and a user adds two words to that scanner.

There should be no space before the first word.

Only one space between the two words.

And no space after the second word.

i.e.

```
'hello world' is correct
```

but

```
'hello world bye' 
' hello world' 
'hello word ' 
'hello  world'
```

are all incorrect.

I've tried to use regex, but with no success.

EDIT: Only letters a to z allowed (uppercase and lower)

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: Do you mean a `java.util.Scanner`? Show some code since this is very unclear.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Are upper-case letters allowed or disallowed?

Comment: Yes they are both allowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
if (input.matches("\\p{Alpha}+ \\p{Alpha}+")) { // same as "[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+"
    // good
} else {
    // bad
}
```

I edited it to use the posix character class after you clarified that upper-case letters are also allowed.

Comment: +1 or maybe `input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+")` if large caps are ok.

Comment: @assylias: OP said only `a-z` are allowed.

Comment: Agreed - it was a maybe! Written vs. actual requirement sometimes tend to differ ;-)

Comment: Right. In most cases people who know how to write the actual requirement are also able to transform them into code.